# Can a precompiled header be used as part of a library that will be statically linked?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, precompiled-headers

I believe I understand the basics concerning precompiled headers and I can't think of any reason why a precompiled header couldn't be used inside a of library, but I've been told that it's either not possible or shouldn't be done (can't remember which).

I have a project where a shared library will be statically linked by multiple others and I would like to use precompiled headers inside the shared library for my external STL/Boost dependencies but I'm not sure if it's possible. I'm targeting OS X and Windows systems and common searches for details seem to point more towards Windows solutions involving `stdafx.h` which leads me to believe that using precompiled headers is customarily a Windows practice.

My question is simply this:

Can/should I use a precompiled header inside of a library that I'll be linking statically to other projects? If not, is using a convenience header for, say, all of my STL/Boost dependencies a good thing to pursue? I'm referring to something like this:

```
// common.h
#pragma once

#include <boost/this>
#include <boost/that>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <other_stl_header>

// Foo.h
#include "common.h"

class Foo { ... }

// Foo.cpp

#include "Foo.h"
...
```

---

EDIT: I should specify, I have no expectation that the precompiled header be shared with anything other than the library I'm compiling. My question is related to whether or not it's possible to create a precompiled header that is used for the compilation of *that* library.

Comment: Precompiled headers are a thing only before linking. It's basically a partial object file that serves as a template for all translation units that include it. It makes no sense to share them, because they're a compiler detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have finished the compilation, there is no more usage for precompiled header and they have no effect on the linkage stage (that includes the shared library and any other linkable components). You can use it to speed up the compilation of your shared library but that's it, the static library is an outcome of the compilation, with or without precomiled headers usage.

Comment: Your answer implies that it is possible and if I find a speed increase in the compilation, then I should do it. Is that correct?

Comment: It can speed up only the compilation of your shared library. Whether it's worth it is your call. However, from the question it seems that you mainly want to speed up the compilation of other projects that statically link with your library - for such usage there won't be any change after you have finished with the shared library compilation (which normally should be done only once)

Comment: I think I must have phrased my question incorrectly or am unsure of what exactly to ask. I am not concerned with a speed increase of the clients of the library, just in whether or not using a precompiled header for the shared library is possible. I believe you've answered my question though.

Comment: @vmrob the whole point is, during linkage, PCH don't exist. Or, the other way around _during compilation, shared libraries **don't exist**!_ Everything the compiler knows in that phase is translation units (so: source and header files). So if you have it _pre-compiled_ it contains only information that would be in headers anyways, and it doesn't matter whether your objects will get statically or dynamically linked in the end. Use the proper compilation flags while generating the PCH, though.

Answer (score 1):

A precompiled header is not an executable or any kind of linkable format. The compiler itself can define any kind of format for a precompiled haeder. Maybe it is simply tokenized, maybe some other includes and the definitions of other includes are already evaluated. The only intention for precompiled headers is a speed up for the compiler.

gcc also uses precompiled headers on demand but it is not a common practice to use this feature. gcc generates `.gch` files for the output of precompile stage.

The simple answer to your question: No

Comment: An important addendum: Even if two compilers say they have precompiled headers, nothing says that the two compilers will have the same format. So if a library uses one compiler, and a user of the library use another compiler, it might not be compatible.

Comment: Also different versions of the same compiler can use different formats as well.

Comment: Perhaps it's a miscommunication on my part then, but my expectation was that the precompiled header information would be compiled into the library file. Is this not what would happen? I didn't expect to share the output of the precompilation with anything.

Comment: @vmrob: No, it wouldn't. The results of pre-compilation are _inputs_ to subsequent compilation steps; the _outputs_ from those steps go into the library.